# Using Nested Intermediate Tables

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm working with Laravel 4 and trying to setup a table structure for handling the following problem.

- I have 3 tables: Players, Teams & Seasons
- For each season, I will have multiple teams assigned and each team will have multiple players assigned.
- I need to maintain historical data for each season, so I can't just connect the tables directly because changing the base player/teams tables would affect all seasons that way.

I connected the Seasons -> Teams table by using an intermediate table `teams_in_season` as follows:

```
class Season extends \Eloquent
{
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Team', 'teams_in_season');
    }
}
```

That works as expected.  The issue comes when I want to setup the player assignment.  Naturally, I want to relate the teams to players so my line of thinking is that I need to create an intermediate table off of another intermediate table.  Ex:

`seasons -> teams_in_season -> players_in_teams -> players`

If I went Seasons -> Players, that would work except that I wouldn't be able to eager load it that way.

`seasons -> players_in_season -> players`

```
$season->teams->players->get();
```

Essentially, the way the user enters data is to create a season, assign teams, assign players to teams, and then eventually add scoring.  All data entered needs to be maintained and therefore the intermediate tables are necessary.

So, here's my question(s):

1. Can I nest/chain intermediate tables like this?
2. Is there a better way I can setup what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted a few different ideas (including Colin's answer), but decided to go a different route here.  The main thing is that I felt that using `$season->seasonTeams->teams()` was a bit difficult to read.  Also, attempting to chain an intermediary table off of another intermediary table felt a bit odd as well.  The solution I came up with was this:

For teams, I stayed with my original design of seasons -> teams_in_seasons -> teams which allows me to lookup the instanced teams using `$season->teams()` and any pivot data necessary therein using the following relationship for the seasons model:

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Team', 'teams_in_season');
}
```

and inverse on teams:

```
public function seasons()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Season', 'teams_in_season');
}
```

For players, instead of chaining off of the existing pivot table `teams_in_season`, I decided instead to connect the pivot table `players_in_teams` to both the seasons and teams table.  To connect these together, I decided to use the Query Builder to build my own queries as follows on the Team model:

```
public function players($season_id, $team_id)
{
    return DB::table('players')
        ->select(DB::raw('players.*'))
        ->join('players_in_team', 'players.id', '=', 'players_in_team.player_id')
        ->where('season_id', '=', $season_id)
        ->where('team_id', '=', $team_id)
        ->orderBy('last_name');
}
```

this will allow me to eager load the players for a given season team as follows:

```
$team->players($season->id, $team->id)->get()
```

This is a bit unorthodox, perhaps, but it works well for my purposes.  I couldn't find another method that made as much sense logically to me.  It also has the side effect of allowing me to add a method onto the Seasons model that will allow me to eager load all of the players for a given season such as:

```
Season::find(1)->players
```

Comment: You can bring this back into the normal routine without much work. Season::players() and Team::players() are both $this->hasMany('Player'). Beyond that look at using scopes to encapsulate some of this into custom query builder methods. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Player::season(1)->team(5)->get();
Season::find(1)->players()->team(5)->get();

Comment: Interesting, I haven't read up on scopes yet but I think that is the missing piece here.  A combination of that and the method I chose to go sounds really good.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult problem. You will need to associate the players to the pivot table between teams and seasons. For that reason I would probably set that up as it's own model.

**Relationships**

- Season hasMany SeasonTeam
- SeasonTeam belongsTo Team
- SeasonTeam belongsToMany Player

**Eager Loading**

Here is how you would list all the teams with their player roster using strictly the relationship methods and eager loading. This is 4 queries.

```
$season = Season::with('seasonTeams.players', 'seasonTeams.team')->find(1);

foreach ($season->seasonTeams as $seasonTeam)
{
    echo $seasonTeam->team->name;

    foreach ($seasonTeam->players as $player)
    {
        echo $player->name;
    }
}
```

**Joins**

I won't draw out the details here but you could also use joins in the query builder to pull players that were part of a team playing in a given season. Check out the link below.

http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries#joins

Comment: @Colin - Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm revising my code to see if that will work for me.  Using this method, you have SeasonTeam belonging to the Players table, but since I will need the players to be instanced as well, would you suggest that I create another Pivot table between SeasonTeam and Players (let's call it SeasonPlayers for example)?

Comment: Yes, the belongsToMany relationship uses a pivot table between the two entities. You don't need a model to represent that but you could. SeasonTeam is a little abnormal but I think it's a good solution in this instance. These are the tables I had in mind: seasons, seasonteams, teams, players, player_seasonteam